# Undo keyboard shortcut debian 8 GNOME 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, debian-jessie, undo

I can be short about this, I'm used to that `Ctrl-z` clears my previous action, for example when typing. Now running Debian 8 With GNOME 3 it does not work, when I press `Ctrl-z` the "Enter a command" dialog is shown.What is the debian/GNOME3 equivalent for `Ctr-z` (undo) or even better how can I make `Ctrl-z` do the Undo'ing?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en is probably what you a looking for. Let me know if it helps and I'll type it up as an answer proper so you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I already been through this, nothing mentioned about undo-shortcut or something like it.

Comment: So it is not the shortcut but the "undo" functionality you are after, right? What exactly are you trying to undo?

Comment: Yes it is the undo function. Usage example: when making typos.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've defined a custom keybinding for Ctrl+z, to clear it you can remove the custom shortcut, or re-assign the shortcut key:
Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Custom Shortcuts